# Error updating Ubuntu 20.04 php problem mcrypt

Tags: package-management, updates, dependencies

When trying to update my server I get the following. What do I do wrong?

```
Reading package lists…
Building dependency tree…
Reading state information…
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php-mcrypt : Depends: php8.2-mcrypt but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 does not use PHP 8.2 by default, so it would appear there are different versions installed, perhaps with the Ondrej PPA. Conflicts aside, you may want to start [with this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/1222991).

Comment: that was the problem. Thanks. Solved it using the answer you linked to